# Need ideas for ScheduledTask to copy file from CompA to CompB

Tags: powershell

So, I'm fairly locked down in my environment, but maybe there's still a way I haven't thought of to get this done...

Need to have a flat file copied from Computer A to Computer B preferably by Scheduled Task that can run whether or not anyone is logged in.  I was trying to use PSExec using the SYSTEM account to start a remote session of Powershell (psexec -s \remotecomputername powershell.exe c:\batch\script.ps1), calling my script which would then use a defined set of credentials to copy the file.

My challenge is two-fold.

1. A GPO is enforced on the machines that prevent the storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication on the local system.  So I'm stuck with the SYSTEM account to start this with.
2. A second GPO is enforced that effectively disables computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation by defining the policy but containing no entries (blank).  I ran into this when I created my script (below).  It calls a pre-defined username and then a previously defined password (encrypted) for that user to then use as credentials to map a drive and copy the file, but with delegation effectively blocked, this won't work.

Am I dead in the water or can you think of another way to accomplish this?

Here's my original script...

```
$ComputerName = "\\RemoteComputerName\D$" 
$UserName = "MyAcccountName" 
$Password = Get-Content 'c:\batch\EncryptedPwdFile.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $Password 
New-PSDrive -Name M -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $computername  -Credential $credential
Copy-Item -path C:\Batch\TestFolder\TestFile2.txt -Destination "J:\testfile2.txt"
```

Comment: ask your admin to schefule the task via gpo ? but as you are not the admin the question fall offtopic.

Comment: If you need network access, you shouldn't be using the `SYSTEM` account, you should be using the `Network Service` account.  Might that be why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's probably a lot of ways to script this, I personally prefer to use a program designed with such a thing in mind.  The program [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) comes to mind and it's capable of doing exactly what you're asking.  It can backup files/folders, create tasks to run automatically without anyone logged in, and it can save credentials for the source and destination.  One thing to keep in mind is that if your sysadmins have a GPO set, they could potentially monitor logins, and they could possibly detect your scheduled task if they look deep enough.  But considering you're using the SYSTEM account, it's kinda doubtful as that is one account that users should not be allowed to use, (unless your terminology is a bit off).

Comment: Thanks Blerg, I'll look into that.  I can only hope our Info Assurance folks will approve the program.  My organization is hyper vigilant and it's quicker to let your hair gray out completely and then fall out before they'll approve new software like this.

Comment: To quote their website: "Our Free Software may be used indefinitely for personal, educational, charity, government, **and commercial** use. It is 100% free with no strings attached."  If they're telling you that you should copy and or execute scripts with the SYSTEM account, they're not very bright at all.  That account has more access than an administrative account; and you need to be administrative to use it in the first place.  **NEVER give more rights than necessary in computers, especially when using scripts.**

Comment: I finally got it to work...Since the password file had to be encrypted by the user calling it (NT Authority\SYSTEM in my case) I called PSEXEC as the system account and interactive (psexec -s -i) to create the password file.  After that, it was simple to create the Scheduled Task, running as SYSTEM to call powershell and the script file.  Everything works perfectly!  Thanks all for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work...Since the password file had to be encrypted by the user calling it (NT Authority\SYSTEM in my case) I called PSEXEC as the system account and interactive (psexec -s -i) to create the password file.  After that, it was simple to create the Scheduled Task, running as SYSTEM to call powershell and the script file.  Everything works perfectly!  Thanks all for looking.